# Can we create an object from an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class

How does this work since we can not create an object from an abstract class?
In this class I have declared an `Alien` array, and `Alien` class is an abstract class.
How does the creation work in the constructor?

```
public class AlienPack {

    private  Alien[] aliens;  //composition 

    //cons with para of array size 
    public AlienPack(int numAliens) {
        aliens = new Alien [numAliens]; //how can we create objects from AC????????????
    }

    public void addAlien(Alien newAlien, int index) {
        aliens[index] = newAlien;
    }

    public Alien[] getAliens() {
        return aliens;
    }

    public int calculateDamage() {
        int damage = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<aliens.length; i++)            // Call getDamage() from each alien to
            damage += aliens[i].getDamage();             // calculate total damage??????????????????????????
        return damage;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'aliens = new Alien [numAliens];'
This will create an array of aliens and size of array is numAliens. array will be initialized with null objects. It doesn't create alien objects.

Comment: The line in your constructor does not create any `Alien` objects.  It just allocates an array which could hold `Alien` objects.  Unless you begin adding `Alien` objects to the array, every index is just `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key distinction is that you created a **variable** of type `Alien[]`. Think of this as the place to store any Aliens that you might create. You haven't tried to create any to store there with something like:

```
1. Alien a = new Alien();
2. aliens[0] = a;
```

And this is where an error will get thrown. The right side of the `=` is where the object gets "created" on line 1. (Although it can't be created because it's abstract) The left side is where a reference variable `a` is created to store an Alien.Which would be fine on its own, as in your case. Abstract / Interface type variables are fine on their own, we can then store concrete implementations of those Abstract / Interface types in those variables.

Answer (score 7):

You aren't creating any instance of `Alien`. You are creating an **array**, where each element is `null` and may contain any instance of a concrete class that extends `Alien`.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you have created an empty array able to hold references to objects of classes that extend from the `Alien` class. But you have not yet instantiated any such objects. So that array remains empty.

Your next step is to create concrete subclasses of abstract `Alien`.

```java
public class Martian extends Alien { … }
public class Saturnian extends Alien { … }
```

Create an empty holder for objects of these concrete classes. No Alien instances yet, no constructors called on Alien nor on the two subclasses. Creating this empty array with no `Alien` objects is like building a bookcase with no books. Having empty shelves ready to hold books does not create the books.

```
Alien[] aliens = new Alien[3] ;  // Empty container. Three slots holding `null`. No `Alien`, `Martian`, or `Saturnian` objects exist yet.
```

You can then instantiate objects of those various subclasses while referring to them as `Alien` objects. That is [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) in action.

As we create each `Martian` or `Saturnian` object that is also simultaneously a `Alien` object, we put a reference to said object into a slot of the array.

```java
aliens[0] = new Martian( … ) ;
aliens[1] = new Martian ( … ) ,
aliens[2] = new Saturnian( … ) ;
```

At this point, we have an array of 3 `Alien` objects (2 `Martian` objects, and 1 `Saturnian` object). Actually, we have an array of three *references* to those three objects. The objects live elsewhere in memory.

Next we use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) rather than an array to collect three aliens. Same effect, but the [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) are more convenient and flexible than arrays.

```java
List< Alien > aliens =
    List.of(
        new Martian( … ) ,
        new Martian ( … ) ,
        new Saturnian( … ) ;
    )
;
```